# Breakpoint does not get triggered in VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, breakpoints, cpython

I set a breakpoint on the function `tuplecontains` in `Objects/tupleobject.c`.

Then I run `make -s -j2`, `./python.exe`, `1 in (1, 2, 3)`

But the breakpoint does not get triggered.

How do I trigger the breakpoint?

Comment: The default Python debugger in VS Code does not debug C code. You should try a debugger that is specialized in debugging C code.

Comment: How does one do that, I use PyCharm mostly. I installed VS Code to debug the C code in cpython, but am stuck.

Comment: Show us your run settings!

Comment: there are a lot of settings. It shows to customize Run and Debug create a launch.json file. When I click on `Run and Debug` then it gives `fatal error: 'Python.h' file not found`